# The principle of recursion

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

In an introductory set theory class we've come to defining the natural numbers as a triple $(N,s,0)$ where $s$ is the successor function(with 3 axioms, not going to go into great depth here, not the point of the question) which allow you to prove the principle of mathematical induction, the next powerful theorem we're trying to prove is that for any other "counting system" $(X, t, x)$ where $X$ is a set, and $ x\in X$ we can find a unique mapping $f: N \to X$ with the property that $f(s(n)) = t(f(n))$

This is powerful because it gives meaning to the notion of recursive definition, so I would like to come to terms with a proof for it. I believe I've proven the uniqueness quality, but I haven't managed to prove the existence component satisfactorily.

Ny attempt was to define another quantity
$f_n = \{y \in X|\exists y'\in X[\exists m\ \in N[t(y') \in f_m]]\}$

And then trying to prove that there is exactly one element in each f_n (through induction, defining $f_0$ "manually" ) I'm not going into the specifics of this, because I believe I've already done something illegal, I've already defined something which is dependent on the definition of something else, which has not yet been defined, so I have already essentially assumed recursive definitions work, my thought was that I could do induction with the premise of "being defined" as in, let my base case be $f_0$ "is defined" but I'm not aware of this phrase itself having any real meaning, and from this point on, I am rather stuck, as everything I try seems to assume exactly what I'm trying to prove, I would appreciate a hint on how to proceed with this problem, but preferably not a full solution

Comment: Use the recursion you know to define partial functions which will turn out to be initial segments of the function you want.  Then define the final function to be the union of those partial functions.